# Strange behavior when combining Bootstrap 4 dropdown & collapse

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I am combining Bootstrap dropdown and collapse in a very simple way. When choosing an entry from the dropdown, the corresponding collapse item should be shown after the current collapse item is hidden. So I use `.collapse('hide')` for hiding the current item, waiting for `hidden.bs.collapse` to be fired and then `.collapse('show')`to show the new collapse item. What is strange is, that after a couple of times (6-10 times) choosing an entry  from the dropdown the class `show`is added to two collapse items, then to three and so on. I realy can't see what I am doing wrong.

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/roman_soerensen/pen/yLaNKKa) with the code to reproduce.

Any help is appreceated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, it never is a good idea to add an eventhandler on click to an item again and again ;)

What I had first, is this:

```
;(function ( $ ) {

$( document ).ready( function () {
    let $dd_btn = $( '.dropdown-item', '#history' );

    $dd_btn.on( 'click', function () {
        let date     = $( this ).data( 'date' ).toString(),
            $target  = $( '#date_' + date.replace('/','_') ),
            $current = $( '.history-content__single.show' );

        if ( ! $target.hasClass( 'show' ) ) {
            $current.collapse( 'hide' );
            $current.on( 'hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
                $( '.dropdown-toggle', '#history' ).text( $( this ).data( 'date' ) );
                $target.collapse( 'show' );
            } );
        }
    } );
} );
})( jQuery );
```

so the following was added on every click

```
$current.on( 'hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $( '.dropdown-toggle', '#history' ).text( $( this ).data( 'date' ) );
    $target.collapse( 'show' );
} );
```

The working solution is this:

```
;(function ( $ ) {

$( document ).ready( function () {
    let $dd_btn = $( '.dropdown-item', '#history' ),
        date = '',
        $target = '';

    $dd_btn.on( 'click', function () {
        date    = $( this ).data( 'date' ).toString(),
        $target = $( '#date_' + date.replace('/','_') );

        if ( ! $target.hasClass( 'show' ) ) {
            $( '.history-content__single.show' ).collapse( 'hide' );
        }
    } );
  
  $( '.history-content__single' ).on( 'hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $( '.dropdown-toggle', '#history' ).text( date );
    $target.collapse( 'show' );
  } );
} );
})( jQuery );
```